# How do I fix vertex error?

Tags: vertices, retopology

[image][image]

[image]

https://pasteall.org/blend/b26e8d74f5974163a1ef6b1c932ab26f

I want to remove this error So I try to move vertex, but when I enter *Edit Mode* it does not exist. How can I solve this problem?

There is a face that penetrates the center of the character, but I can't fix it. If you enter *Edit Mode* to fix it, the face disappears.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what kind of problem do you have or what is your issue

Comment: you should show us which vertex you mean and how to you want the result to look like? a sketch would be good...and an arrow, where your vertex is

Comment: Sorry, It's my fault. I wasn't used to asking questions. So I fixed the question

Comment: remove the multires modifier and add a subdivision surface instead of it.

Comment: @lemon Thank you! I fix it

Comment: Better keep the modifier and fix the mesh ;-) See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These glitches happen when you modify/add vertices to a mesh which has a *Multires* modifier or in your case, the mesh has **duplicated vertices and a hole** at the back:

[image: hole in the mesh]

In *Edit* mode, select the vertices at the back and merge them (<kbd>M</kbd>). X-ray mode helps because two of the 3 vertices you need to merge are inside.

Then do a <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* with `0.1` in the popup dialog at the left bottom of the screen. 0.1 because your model is 9m big. This will remove a hundred duplicated vertices.

There is still a glitch at the inside of the belly button. You can restore the shape of the base mesh with the ***Multires Displacement Eraser" brush**. The challenge is that you have to target the rogue vertice (the tip of the spike) to fix it. Click a few times to restore its position:

[image: belly button]

Last but not least you should fix the **overlapping/zero faces** at the neck/collar area. You will see it when you move the pole vertice along the Y-axis:

[image: overlapping faces]

Comment: Thank you blunder. I changed the modi fire, but something didn't work out. Thank you for correcting it.